# Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected Token illegal javascript with txt file

Tags: php, javascript

I'm testing a script to automate advertisement read from a txt file) i want to use this because it was the one i already had and was working and only needed a few changes, however, something stopped working and i dont know what's wrong, i'm checking the output and everthing seems fine on the javascript but for some reason it doesn't work, it comes with unexpected token illegal and with the uncaught syntax error 
below is the code. Any Help is appreciated

PHP/javascript combined code

```
<?php 
    $adsf = "test.txt";
    $count = 0;
    $frd = fopen ($adsf,'r');
    $artest = array();
    $artest2 = array();
    $artest3 = array();
      while(!feof($frd))
       {

         $artest[$count] = fgets($frd);
         $count++;
        }
      fclose($frd);


      $t = 0;
      while($t < $count)
        {
        $artest2[$t] = str_replace("\n" ,'', $artest[$t]);
          $artest3[$t] ="\"".$artest2[$t]."\", ";

          $t++;
        }    





          unset($artest3[$t - 1]);
          shuffle($artest3);
          $t = 0;
         while ($t < $count)
           {

            $jsr = $jsr.$artest3[$t - 1];
            $t++;

            }

               //$jsr. = "\"test 1 test 2 test 3\", ";
            $jsr = $jsr." \"Advertise Here come to Lot 28 or Click <a href=\\\"pub.php\\\" target=\\\"_blank\\\">HERE</a> For More Information\" ";
       ?>


             var avs = new Array ( <?echo $jsr; ?>);

             //var cron = 60;
              var sub = 0;
             function show5(){
                if (!document.layers&&!document.all&&!document.getElementById)
                return




               //change font size here to your desire
               myclock="<font size='2' face='Arial' ><b>"+avs[sub]+"</b></font>"
              if (document.layers){
                  document.layers.liveclock.document.write(myclock)
                  document.layers.liveclock.document.close()
                  }
                 else if (document.all)
                   liveclock.innerHTML=myclock             
                   else if (document.getElementById)
                    document.getElementById("liveclock").innerHTML=myclock

                    ;
                  sub++;

                  if(sub > <? echo $count - 1; ?>)
                   {
                      sub = 0;

                       }
                   setTimeout("show5()",5000)
                 }


             window.onload=show5
```

and the  problem comes on the array, if i put nothing on the txt file everythng works ok but if i try tiping any thing, used to be working but now comes with the "uncaught syntax error unexpected token illegal" and i checked the quotes and are fine.

Comment: You need to give us the *full* error message, and indicate which line it is failing on.

Comment: `document.layers` feels like we're back to 90's...

Comment: yes, is a really old script that i just edited, I don't need anything fancy, since it is only something internal. the line is failing on is on the array avs = new array ( " ", "" ) .. etc, it might be something i read about the copy/paste problem. but i reset everything back to normal and still started having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad bad bad bad bad BAD idea:

```
         var avs = new Array ( <?echo $jsr; ?>);
```

Look at all the escaping you have to do while you're building up `$jsr` in the PHP code. Whereas, if you were doing this properly, with json_encode(), you'd simply build up an array of values in PHP, e.g.

```
$jsr = array();
$jsr[] = "Look ma, a single quote '!!!!"
$jsr[] = 'Hey pa, double quote here "!!!';
```

and then

```
var avs = <?php echo json_encode($jsr) ?>;
```

Comment: Thanks, the script is a really old script that was working for something but i had to edit it for a new purpose, well, just few edits, however, with the new array, I want to add the array items from a txt file new line per item. and some of it will be html.. although not all any ideas on how it can be done?

Comment: Thanks Marc, Got it working, changed a few things and works great, it is different from the array i was used to, but as long as it works, its ok i just had to remove the \r\n characters Thanks again